# Loading datetime64[ns] column to BQ table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a table from a pandas dataframe to a BQ table. One of the columns I am importing is of type datetime64[ns]. Even though I don't get an error anywhere the format of the entries is wrong. This is the code and the output:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = "test_table"

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("columnA", "TIMESTAMP", mode="REQUIRED"),
    # Add other schema fields as needed
]

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=schema,
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete

table = client.get_table(table_id)
```

Instead of getting the expected output in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' for the datetime column, I get a long integer, e.g. "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

I tried not specifying the column type in the schema at all but I got the same output.
I tried adding source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON in the job_config, but this method is not allowed when reading from pandas dataframe as I understood.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert your datetime column to UNIX timestamp via:

```py
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = (df['date'] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
```

Edited based on comment:
you can do this with an additional package called `pandas_gdq`:

```py
from pandas_gbq import to_gbq

project_id = 'your-project-id'
dataset_id = 'your-dataset-id'
table_id = 'test_table'

to_gbq(
    df,
    f'{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}',
    project_id=project_id,
    if_exists='replace',
    table_schema=schema,
    progress_bar_type=None,
    table_config=job_config,
    if_exists='replace',
    if_exists='replace',
    query=f'SELECT *, TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(columnA AS INT64)) AS columnA FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}`',
)
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to handle this through the BQ client rather than converting the dataframe that am reading from.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This functionality is part of a bigger codebase and it would be rather timeconsuming to do that for all the columns of that datatime type. I was wondering if I was missing any useful SchemaField in the job config to take care of that for me as I am loading quite a lot of tables with various datetime object columns.

Comment: can't you select certain columns of your interest?

Comment: Yes I can. The function is part of a pipeline which will be fed new tables to load to BQ which is why I didn't want to modify the input tables but rather the loading method.

Comment: IMHO, eventually you need to select either modifying your dataframe or your table unless you want a separate query